# Collect Row # of Matching Elements in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I'm trying to collect the row numbers that match a certain value in multiple columns of an excel worksheet. The behavior I'm looking for reflects the table below:

```
|---|---------|---------|---------|
| 1 | A       | B       | A       |
|---|---------|---------|---------|
| 2 | B       | A       | A       |
|---|---------|---------|---------|
| 3 | C       | A       | C       |
|---|---------|---------|---------|
| 4 | A       | A       | C       |
|---|---------|---------|---------|
| 5 | C       | B       | B       |
|---|---------|---------|---------|
| 6 | A       | B       | B       |
|---|---------|---------|---------|
|   | Results |         |         |
|---|---------|---------|---------|
| A | 1, 4, 6 | 2, 3, 4 | 1, 2    |
|---|---------|---------|---------|
| C | 3, 5    |         | 3, 4    |
|---|---------|---------|---------|
```

So far, I've managed to achieve the result I'm looking for by doing individual `IF` calls per cell to create a mirrored version of the table, and reducing it from there, but its a pain to extend more generally. Thoughts?

Comment: You're trying to get all the results in a single cell (for instance, all the results of A for 1st column in a single cell)? I don't think that functions are suitable here...

Comment: If possible. I managed to achieve the effect by using `SMALL`  and then collecting the output with concatenation.

Comment: But for extended number of rows, it'll become more tedious, yes? What if there was a function, and you have to press F9 to get the list? That means that you first put the function everywhere in the Results table and then use F9 in each formula to turn the results into lists? This is still quite tedious, but avoids having to concatenate.

Comment: Would a macro be acceptable or must it be a function?

Comment: Macros and VB scripts are fine. I wasn't sure if Excel 2011 for OS X supported scripting, but it looks like it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not pretty, but it's short and a start.

[image]

```
Sub collectRows()

Set rngInput = Range("C2:E7")
Set rngFilter = Range("A10:A11")

For Each rngCell In rngInput
    If Not rngFilter.Find(what:=rngCell, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
        rngFilterRow = rngFilter.Find(what:=rngCell, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
        Cells(rngFilterRow, rngCell.Column) = Cells(rngFilterRow, rngCell.Column) & ", " & rngCell.Row
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be done in Excel.  Just thinking outside the box, if you loaded the data into sql server, it'd be easy to run a query to get this information.

Comment: Sadly, yes. Most of the people using the spreadsheets aren't familiar with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this with Google Apps Script for any who might find it useful:

```
// Example Usage:
//    =collectMatches("A", C2:C5)
function collectMatches(target, columns) {
  collection = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    if (columns[i][0].toLowerCase() === target.toLowerCase()) {
      Logger.log(target)
      collection.push(i+1)
    }
  };
  return collection.join(', ');
}
```